# ios app dynamically loads data from website made on opencart

Tags: ios, database, api, opencart, integration

I have a website made on opencart and now I want an ios app for my website which dynamically loads data from the website. their database should be integrated so that when a change is made to any one of them it should make changes on both website and application.
Does someone provide me that API??

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is an API like you wish. You have to develop an API gateway as a middleware between your mobile apps and OpenCart backend. And I think it’s a simple job since all your data already exists in OpenCart database.